# afl-gcc-fast complains about incompatible GCC and plugin versions even though they are the same

Tags: plugins, compiler-errors, compilation, fuzzing, afl-fuzz

I am trying to compile this simple program with afl-gcc-fast.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%s", "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I then get this error:

```
afl-cc++4.06a by Michal Zalewski, Laszlo Szekeres, Marc Heuse - mode: GCC_PLUGIN-DEFAULT

[-] PROGRAM ABORT : GCC and plugin have incompatible versions, expected GCC 9.4.0, is 9.4.0
         Location : plugin_init(), instrumentation/afl-gcc-pass.so.cc:482
```

Why does the error occur even though the versions are the exact same? This didn't happen previously to me, but then I probably accidentally changed something in my system and now it no longer works. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!